# How to wait JsDialog response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the `JQuery dialog` and actually I've no problem in this. Now I want replace my `alert confirmation` with a `JQuery Dialog Confirmation`, the problem's that when I show the `JQuery Dialog` the code continue to work and doesn't wait the `JQuery Dialog` response. What I'm trying so is create a mode to wait the `JQuery dialog` result and after it continue the code execution.

**Function fired after button press**

```
function start(title, message, messageButtons)
{  
  //messageButtons => contains the buttons with the function see bottom

    if(confirm)
    {
        jQuery("body").append(
        "<div id='message_box' title='" + title + "'>" +
        "<p>" + message + "</p>" +
        "</div>"
        );    

        jQuery("#message_box").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resize: "auto",
            width: 400,
            height: "auto",
            resizable: false,
            buttons: messageButtons,
            closeOnEscape: true
            });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("No response");
    }
}
```

**Message buttons structure:**

```
  var messageButtons = {};
  messageButtons['OK'] = function() 
  {
       confirm = true;
  };

  messageButtons[EALang['cancel']] = function() 
  {
       confirm = false;
       $('#message_box').dialog('close');
  };
```

The `JQuery Dialog` is displayed correctly but in the browser console I get `No response` before the user select an answer from the `JQuery Dialog`. So the main problem is stop the js code after the `JQuery Dialog` appear, wait the user selection, and later continue the code above. How you can see I valorize the `confirm` variable in the button function, this function are called when the user press the appropriate button and this working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use a callback to execute whatever code you want at a certain point in js.Dialog, it seems to be quite good with callbacks, here is some info about that: http://code.kolmio.com/jsdialog/Docs/Callbacks.html

Also, a way of saving a piece of code to be executed later is to set a time out: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: There is another way to do this?

Comment: Please ask a more specific question.

Comment: You asked me "there is another way to do this", I've told you about callbacks and the time out function, have you looked at these?

Comment: Yeah, but seems a bit difficult, I need a simple way to this.